# customize price of the product

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a gift card application where minimum price of any gift card is already set. eg: 5$
But I want to give an option to the user so that they can add more money to their card eg: 50$. So I will charge them for 50$ now. How to add an input field so that user can add the amount from product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply To add text box you have to create product custom option,,,from `catalog>manage product`

For reference [Click here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-product-custom-options.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I want. Is there any way to add the same custom option for all of my products? I have almost thousands of products. Hope you understand.

Comment: @SandeepGupta for that you can ask new question,,, and if you find my answer helpful then accept it

Comment: @SandeepGupta i think there is free extension avaulable for that http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-manager.html

Comment: I installed this extension but there is no way to add a new custom option from manage custom options screen? :(

Comment: you can check demo or contact extension developr for that @SandeepGupta

Answer (score 2):

In order to do so, you should add a custom option as a text field and create an observer that will change the price accordingly.

How to create a custom price using an observer:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/22638328/magento-add-product-to-cart-with-custom-price-using-observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638328/magento-add-product-to-cart-with-custom-price-using-observer)

Comment: This should be a comment. beware of the downvote functionality.!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already created an observer which can change the price of the product. What I am not able to do is, to create the input field to fill the desired amount on product page.

Comment: then just add product custom option @SandeepGupta

Comment: @Manashvibirla I changed my answer so it looks more like an answer

Comment: Image which is shown in the given link, edits the price that's absolutely fine for me. But I am really not sure what this function (convertPricespanToInput) does and also this line 
$block = new WebDirect_CustomPrice_Block_priceSpanToInput();